# ¿Cómo pintar celdas de excel con UFT ONE? (vbscript)

Tags: vbscript

estoy tratando de guardar en una especie de bitácora todos los datos con los que interactúa UFT one,lo que yo quiero es pintar las celdas desde uft one y hacer bordes, dandole formato y creando una especie de tabla, sin embargo aun no encuentro como.
Intenté con la propiedad RGB que encontró pero me dice que los valores no son válidos.

```
objeto2.Cells(filas,col).RGB 15,20,35
```

Lo coloco sin paréntesis porque si coloco paréntesis me sale error, porque la propiedad es un sub.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolví, dejo el código por si alguien algún día lo necesita.

```
objeto2.Cells(fila,columna).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 139, 139)
```

'objeto2 es el que lleva el nombre de la hoja de excel